# reading excel file by using stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I am trying to develop a tool where the user browses his computer to upload an Excel file, then saves it to a database.  The following code reads the Excel sheet by using a stored procedure, then imports the data to the database.  Now I want to add a feature where the user can also choose specific columns from the Excel file.

My question is:  can I pass the name of the column as a parameter to the stored procedure so only these column are saved, and not the whole Excel file because I tried that and I got an error

The c# code:

```
string CommandText = "spx_ImportFromExcel";

//Read Excel Sheet using Stored Procedure
//And import the data into Database Table
String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = CommandText;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@SheetName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlSheets.SelectedItem.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FilePath", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FolderPath + FileName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@HDR", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rbHDR.SelectedItem.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TableName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtTable.Text;

cmd.Connection = con;
```

The stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spx_ImportFromExcel] (
    @SheetName varchar(20),
    @FilePath varchar(100),
    @HDR varchar(3),
    @TableName varchar(50)
) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000)

    IF OBJECT_ID (@TableName,'U') IS NOT NULL
        SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TableName + ' SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE'
    ELSE
        SET @SQL = 'SELECT * INTO ' + @TableName + ' FROM OPENDATASOURCE'

    SET @SQL = @SQL + '(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Data Source='
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @FilePath + ';Extended Properties=''''Excel 12.0;HDR=' 
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @HDR + ''''''')...[' 
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @SheetName + ']'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

Comment: Usually the error you receive is very valuable, so you should definitely include it.

Comment: Also I'd guess this is wrong: `''''Excel` -- I don't believe the separator is anywhere 2 x `'` but instead it should be `"`

Comment: I would suggest a different approach. Read your Excel file to a DataSet, persist it in memory (session variable), let the user select the column(s) and then recreate the Excel file or csv file from the DataSet.